# v-for with dynamic variable

Tags: vue.js, v-for, vue-i18n

I am working on a Vue app with i18n and want to list items from a large JSON file in the selected languages.

Here is an example JSON file:

```
items: [
  {
    "name_en": "Name",
    "name_de": "Name"
  },
  {
    "year_en": "Year",
    "year_de": "Jahr"
  }
]
```

I would like to get the items with v-for like this:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in data.items" :key="index">
     <p {{item.name_[$i18n.locale]}} </p>
</div>
```

$i18n.local drops the current language code such as 'en' or 'de'. But what the correct syntax is to get the item.name_en or item.name_de?

Thank you for all your suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

You're almost there: it's just the square brackets are misplaced + a bit of help with concatenating strings:

```
 <p>{{ item['name_' + $i18n.locale] }}</p>
```

However, I am not the biggest fan of in-template string interpolation (personal preference). You can consider offloading/abstracting that logic into a computed property:

```
computed: {
    i18nameKey() {
        return `name_${this.$i18n.locale}`;
    }
}
```

Then, you can use `i18nameKey` in your template as such:

```
<p>{{ item[i18nameKey] }}</p>
```